# How to find polar coordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I am having some trouble figuring out how to get the polar coordinates for the following integral:

$\int e^{-x^2} dx$ on $\Bbb R=[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty) $

First I have found g such that g'= $e^{-x^2}$

So now I have

$\int e^{-(x^2+y^2)} dx\,dy$

I know that $r{^2}$ = $x^2+y^2$

so

$\int e^{-r^2} r drdθ$

I am not sure how I can find the polar coordinates for this.

The answer says that the integral is from  $0< r<\infty$ and $0<\theta<\pi/2$ but I don't know how to get that answer.

Comment: Why is there no $y$ in the original integral? Are you sure you're copying down the correct problem?

Comment: I think you pose the wrong question. Do you intend to calculate $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$?

Comment: @Andrei yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is why

$$\int \int_ {[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)} e^{-(x^2+y^2)} dxdy   =\int _{0}^{\infty} \int _{0}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)} dxdy$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int _{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2} r drdθ$$

Well, the first equality is by Fubini's Theorem which describes double integrals into iterated integras.

The second equality is describing the first quadrant, in polar coordinates.

If you visulize the first quadrant as the interior of a quarter  circle with radius infinity and the center at the origin, you can see the range of $0<\theta<\pi /2$ and $0<r<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$$
Since all the values are positive, we can calculate $I^2$ instead, then take the square root
$$I^2=\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx\right)\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2} dy\right)$$
I choose different variable name for the second term.
Now we can write this as a double integral:
$$I^2=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)} dx\ dy$$
Now we transform in polar coordinated. $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $dxdy=r dr d\theta$. Also the limits are now $r\in[0,\infty)$ and $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$
So $$I^2=\int_0^\infty rdr\int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta e^{-r^2} $$
Notice that the exponential does not depend on $\theta$, so we can take that outside, and using $$\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
you get $$I^2=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}rdr$$
We can now change the variable $r^2=z$ and $2rdr=dz$ so $$I^2=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\infty dz e^{-z}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
Therefore $I=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and writing that out however I have the solution in the book. I am just confused on why r∈[0,∞) and θ∈[0,π/2]. Could you explain that please? Is θ∈[0,π/2] because its in the first quadrant?

Comment: Yes. Since both $x$ and $y$ have positive values only, the pair $(x,y)$ is in the first quadrant, so the angle would be from $0$ to $\pi/2$. If you would calculate instead the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, the angle would go from $0$ to $2\pi$

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute the double integral $$\iint_{\mathbf R_+\times\mathbf R_+}\mkern-27mu\mathrm e^{-x^2-y^2}\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y=$$
 in polar coordinates, and apply *Fubini's theorem*.

Comment: yes that is correct however i am not sure how to get the polar coordinates of that.

Comment: Did you consider fhe transformation $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$?

Comment: $-x^2-y^2=-r^2$ and the substitution formulæ cartesian $\to$ polar say you have to replace $\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$ with $r\,\mathrm d r\,\mathrm d \theta$.

Comment: yes i would have $\int e^{-r^2} r drdθ$